# eclipse color theme broken on Mac

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, themes

eclipse color theme is failing to properly change background color for themes

[dark theme background not dark enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQe9Y.jpg)

[light theme background remains same shade of dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsWuc.jpg)

The reason I'm really hoping to fix this issue is I prefer very dark backgrounds for higher contrast. It's easier on my eyes and reduces strain. Am hoping its either a setting/preferences issue or a quick hack to fix, but it'd be cool to be able to raise a bug with whoever is maintaining this plugin. Thanks!

EDIT: my post on eclipse subreddit got the solution. the DevStyle plugin is better maintained, has more useful theming/styling options, and is not buggy.

Comment: [Here is the code of the plugin you are talking](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme). Go for it and fix it.

Comment: I find the standard Dark theme that comes with Eclipse is fine on macOS without having to install additional plug-ins.